# Bell number with minimum bound on partition size

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

I know that the Bell number $B_n$ is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ elements into distinct non-empty subsets. Is there a variant of this number that specifies the minimum number of elements in each particular subset? For example, I want to compute the number of partitions of a set of $n$ elements such that each partition contains at least $m$ elements ($m < n$). How can this be done?

Comment: @bof: Yes, on rereading the question I think that you’re right.

Comment: I don't know if this helps any, but for fixed $m$ there is a closed-form exponential generating function, namely $\exp(e^x-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}x^k/k!)$. More generally, for $I\subseteq\{0\}\cup\mathbb N$ and $J\subseteq\mathbb N$, if we define $B_{I,J,n}$ to be the number of partitions of an $n$-element set such that the number of parts is in $I$ and the size of each part is in $J$, then the exponential generating function is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_{I,J,n}x^n/n! =\exp_I(\exp_J(x))$ where $\exp_K(x) = \sum_{k\in K}x^k/k!$. (If I remember right!)